# SELECT FROM AS and JOIN in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to perform this Query on Laravel?

```
SELECT * 
FROM conversion t1 
     JOIN (SELECT report_id, MAX(id) id 
           FROM conversion 
           GROUP BY report_id ) AS t2 
     ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.report_id = t2.report_id
```

I already read in Laravel Documentary and not find an anything,

I already try in SQL and working but I don't know how to perform this Query in Laravel.

Please help to resolve this, Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the correct solution for your question:

```
$subQuery = \DB::table('conversion')
    ->selectRaw('report_id, MAX(id) id')
    ->groupBy('report_id')
    ->toSql();

$data = \DB::table('conversion t1')
    ->join(\DB::raw('(' . $subQuery . ') as t2'), function ($join) {
        $join->on('t1.id', 't2.id')
            ->on('t1.report_id', 't2.report_id');
    }, null, null, '')
    ->get();
```

If you want to check the query of this one you can use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` in the end.
The output is:

```
select * 
from `conversion t1` 
join (
    select report_id, MAX(id) as id 
    from `conversion` 
    group by `report_id`
) as t2 
on `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id` 
and `t1`.`report_id` = `t2`.`report_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

Didnt have my IDE right now, but it should work this way:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw ('SELECT * 
    FROM conversion t1 
    JOIN (SELECT report_id, MAX(id) id 
       FROM conversion 
       GROUP BY report_id ) AS t2 
       ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.report_id = t2.report_id'));
```